# How long can I travel outside the uk With spouse visa valid till August 2020

Tags: visas, uk-residents

I have spouse visa in the UK till  August 2020 , I might be out the UK more than 6 months  ,can I go back to live with my husband with same spouse visa ? I have resident permit can I use it again for work there?

Comment: Others with better knowledge will answer, however the limit may be no more than 180 days total in any consecutive 12 month period https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/723413/Calculating-continuous-leave-v17.0-EXT.pdf#page6